# C++ Eclipse: stdin in different console than stdout

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, console-application

I encountered a strange of Eclipse on Linux.

I have a simple C++ console program that prints some messages to stdout (cout) which is displayed in a console named "Default [C/C++ Application] ApplicationName" where "ApplicationName" is the name of my executable.

When I try to read a character with getchar() this console does not react to any input. 
I have to switch the console to another console named:  "Default [C/C++ Application] gdb" where I can enter a message which is then read by getchar().

So it looks like stdin and stdout is routed to different consoles during debug. If running the App without debugger from a Console Window outside of Eclipse everything works fine.

How can I make Eclipse use the same console for input and output.

I now installed the latest version of Eclipse Keppler and the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ubuntu 12 and eclipse kepler and program it using same console for input and output. I have tested it with and without GDB.

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819

Answer (score 0):

Mine is Indigo on Linux Mint. It was the version that I got when istalled from the "App-Store".
Will try to install the new Version. Thanks.